# Resuming form load when programmatically interrupted

Tags: c#, winforms

In a C# WinForms project, on the main form load I am populating a DataGridVew, which uses settings that the user can change in another form. To get to that form I first call a simple password entry form and if the password is correct, the db settings form loads.

When the main form loads, it checks the saved db settings (saved in an XML file) to make sure it can connect with those settings. If it does, the methods are called to load all of the databound controls. If it can't find the file or can't connect with the saved settings, I call the password form and then the db settings form.

The problem is, after going to the db settings form and saving valid settings, when that form closes, the DGV on the main form doesn't load.

So in pseudo-code the gist of my process looks like this:

Main Form Class

```
frmMain_Load()
{
    bool bSettingsFileExists = SettingsFileExists();
    bool bCanConnect = TestConnnectionSettings();

    if (bSettingsFileExists && bCanConnect) LoadAllControls();

    if (!bSettingsFileExists || !bCanConnect)
    {
        frmEnterPassword frm = new frmEnterPassword();
        frm.Show();
    }
}

LoadAllControls()
{
    // Load the DGV and other controls using the saved settings
}
```

Password Entry Class

```
frmEnterPassword_Load()
{
    // Password validated
    var frmDbConnectionInfo = new frmDbConnectionInfo();
    frmDbConnectionInfo.Show();
    frmDbConnectionInfo.FormClosed += (obj, args) => { this.Close(); };
    this.Hide();
}
```

DB Connection Settings Class

```
frmDbConnectionInfo_Load()
{
    // Load form with settings
}

btnTestEnteredSettings_Click()
{
    // Verified can connect with the entered settings
    frmXRefTool frmMain = new frmXRefTool();
    frmMain.LoadAllControls();
    this.Close();
}
```

It was my assumption that calling LoadAllControls() in the frmClosing event would do the trick, but it does not. I'm just left with an empty DGV on the main form.

What do I need to do to get the databound controls to load after the user is done in the db connection info form?

Comment: Hi. So, in `frmMain_Load()` expression `if (!bSettingsFileExists || !bCanConnect)` is `true`, so `frmEnterPassword` loads, which automatically loads `frmDbConnectionInfo`. Would it help to call `LoadAllControls()` while closing `frmDbConnectionInfo`?

Comment: Change Show to ShowDialog